# How to apply ClientServer and MVC in Operating System & Computer Networking

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, client-server

In this semester, I need to do a project about Operating System & Computer Networking in C#. The project requires a TCP model but not a web application. I just find a model of another project that relative with my project but I don't know how to deployment it? Can you give me the solution for this?

[model]
[image]

I'm spending a lot time to research about this model in the picture but I don't know how it actually deployment and work :(